# Can we run through javascript local storage pairs? [done]

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am new to javascript local storage, and I want to know how to run through every item in a local storage? Pls tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage) tells it more less:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    let key = localStorage.key(i);
    let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log("The Item of key " + key + " (" + i + ") is: ", value);
}
```

Comment: @Anonymouse Please consider marking one of the solutions as the correct answer. This is the [intendet behaviour of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and tells the system that it should not display this question anymore. You will also [gain reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for accepting an answer.

Comment: done, I marked your answer is right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi please find the below codes:

```
 //Add item in local storage
 localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
 //Get item from local storage
 localStorage.getItem('key')
 //Remove Key From local storage
 localStorage.removeItem('key')
 //Clear local storage
 localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: Yes, you can run through javascript.

Comment: Can you please mark this as "Done"?